# Upsert call in Enterprise WSDL

Tags: soap-api, enterprise

With the help of enterprise wsdl,  I have been trying to make upsert call in Contact where I need to relate the contact with Account . I have an external Id field on Account and trying to use it for upsert.

I am getting the below Error.

> INVALID_TYPE
>                  Must send a concrete entity type.
>                  -1
>                  -1

Below is the request, I am making....please let me know whats wrong here. I am making this request as sys admin.. and have all permission for this object.

```
<urn:upsert>
        <urn:externalIDFieldName>Account.Partner_Number_HDS__c</urn:externalIDFieldName>
            <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Contact"> <!--Zero or more repetitions:--> 
             <FirstName>EnterA</FirstName>
              <LastName>EnterB</LastName>
            <Department>Sales</Department>
            <Job_Title_HDS__c>Account Manager</Job_Title_HDS__c>
            <MobilePhone>456768985</MobilePhone>
            <Email>test@test.com</Email>
            <Account.Partner_Number_HDS__c>PA-74</Account.Partner_Number_HDS__c>   
</urn:sObjects>
</urn:upsert>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just played around this and there is unknown property of nesting parent structure in child object to create child object with parent external Id .

Here is the sample Create Call on contact that I tried by passing Account external Id.Please note you can still use create call only no need for upsert as you don't have externalId for contact.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
 xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
  <urn:SessionHeader>
       <urn:sessionId>00D90000000aRkL!ARIAQCmb6KJfjySnrTbEZ9HFOvnmDi7UOQTe4OzeTTBsF1mrAiwZXc0aGHM.xQgJ58lwWssBXKBqSlNxWhjVgfk5WQoLQfpB</urn:sessionId>
 </urn:SessionHeader>
 </soapenv:Header>
     <soapenv:Body>
   <urn:create>
     <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Contact"> <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
       <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
       <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
       <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <urn:Account xsi:type="urn1:Account"> <!--Zero or more repetitions:-Here I have nested Account Structure so that it helps to associate Account directly-> 
         <UID__c>12345</UID__c>
    </urn:Account>
    </urn:sObjects>
 </urn:create>
   </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is a small video demonstrating this

[Video demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38TEHvmEnZk&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Thanks Mohith. One more question , how can we do it in case of Custom Object. I have custom object lookup on contact, I need to do the same for that . . Custom object field name is Preferred_Country__c which a lookup to Region__C object....Region object also has a external id.  <urn:Preferred_Country_HDS__r xsi:type="urn1:Preferred_Country_HDS__c">  
                           <Test_external_Id__c>India</Test_external_Id__c>
                    </urn:Preferred_Country_HDS__r>

Comment: Thanks Mohith . .I have resolved this for custom object. btw, Nice video..

Comment: Ankit you may like to upvote and mark answered to help others

Comment: Sure. It should help other. I could not find a single example of nested object in Upsert call.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution to insert the records and populate the Lookup field with the help of external id.

```
<urn:Account xsi:type="urn1:Account">  
                          <Partner_number_HDS__c>12345</Partner_number_HDS__c>
                </urn:Account>
                <urn:Preferred_Country_HDS__r xsi:type="urn1:Region_HDS__c">  
                       <Test_external_Id__c>India</Test_external_Id__c>
                </urn:Preferred_Country_HDS__r>
```

here in first 3 lines,

```
  i am giving account object external Id Information ,and after that custom oject external Id information...
<urn:Lookupfieldname  xsi:type="urn1:sobjectName">
    <External_Id__c>12312</External_Id__c>
</urn:lookupfieldName>
```